# Fractal drawing not showing up in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, fractals

Im trying to make a program that plots different julia sets and am first trying to plot the mandelbrot set. However, when i try to plot something on the tkinter canvas nothing shows up. I've also tried to add simple rectangles but it isn't working

```
from tkinter import *
SIZE = 600

class Fractal:
    zoom_list = []

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Julia Set")

        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=SIZE, height=SIZE, bg="#FFFFFF")
        self.canvas.grid(rowspan=11, column=1, sticky=NW)
        self.img = PhotoImage(width=SIZE, height=SIZE)
        self.canvas.create_image((50, 50), image=self.img, state="normal")

        self.plot_button = Button(master, text="plot fractal")
        self.zoom_out_button = Button(master, text="zoom out")
        self.input_field = Entry(master, fg="black", bg="white", width=50)

        self.plot_button.grid(row=10, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.zoom_out_button.grid(row=9, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.input_field.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=W)

    def is_bounded(self, a, b):
        """Checks if a complex number is in the Mandelbrot set returning boolean based on outcome"""
        a = a / 300 - 2.5
        b = b / 300 - 1.5

        c = complex(a, b)
        z = 0
        for i in range(200):
            if abs(z) > 2:
                return False
            z = pow(z, 2) + c
        return True

    def plot_fractal(self):
        """Adds a plot of the mandelbrot set to img and returns None"""
        for y in range(SIZE):
            for x in range(SIZE):
                if self.is_bounded(self, x, y):
                    self.canvas.put("#2596be", (x, y))




def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600+100+100")
    app = Fractal(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I also tried drawing simple rectangles or coloring a point in the canvas but it didn't work

Comment: You need to call plot_fractal() somewhere. Either once before root.mainloop(). Or if its an animation. Add a while True with the plot_fractal() in it after root.mainloop(). If animating, there also seems to be a canvas.update() as well as canvas.delete('all') if you need to remove each previous frame.

Comment: A `Canvas` does not have a `.put()` method - you need to call that on your `PhotoImage` object, instead.

Comment: I think `self.canvas.put("#2596be", (x, y))` should be `self.img.put("#2596be", (x, y))`.  Also `self.is_bounded(self, x, y)` should be `self.is_bounded(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when i try to plot something on the tkinter canvas nothing
> shows up

@Bas van der Linden says, you need to call `plot_fractal` method by adding an `app.plot_fractal(`) on line 50.

@jasonharper says, a `Canvas` does not have a `.put()` method. As @acw1668 says, replace self.canvas with `self.img` on line 41.

@acw1668 says, to remove `self.` on line 40.

On line 50, add this `app.plot_fractal()`

snippet:

```
    def plot_fractal(self):
        """Adds a plot of the mandelbrot set to img and returns None"""
        for y in range(SIZE):
            for x in range(SIZE):
                if self.is_bounded(x, y):
                    self.img.put("#2596be", (x, y))


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600+100+100")
    app = Fractal(root)
    app.plot_fractal()
    root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot: **Wait at least 15 seconds or more** to see the main window pop-up.

[image]